# conflict clicking on a table row

Tags: html, typescript, angular6

i have a table that includes a click on the row that takes me to the details of that table element, and in every row there is a delete icon. when i click on the delete i get a conflit. please help me to solve this problem ?

my manager wants the click on the row to be on all the row

here is my code :

```
<div class="table-responsive datatable spacing-table">
   <table class="table table-striped myt-user-table" [mfData]="myObjects" 
 #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="10">

       <thead class="myt-table-header" align="float-left">
           <th *ngFor='let col of colNames'>{{col}}</th>
           <th *ngIf="isActions"></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr *ngFor='let obj of mf.data' (click)='editObjectEmmitter(obj)'>

            <td *ngFor='let field of myFields' [innerHTML]="obj[field] | applyPure: pipeFn"
                (click)='viewRowEmmitter(obj)' [width]="1/colNames.length*90+'%'" align="float-left"></td>
            <td class="actions" *ngIf="isView || isUpdated || isDeleted || isDesactivated || isActions"
                align="right" width="10%">
                <a *ngIf="isDeleted" (click)='deleteObjectEmmitter(obj)'>
                    <i class="icon-rubbish-bin text-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Supprimer"></i>
                </a>
                <a *ngIf="isDesactivated" (click)='desactivateObjectEmmitter(obj)'>
                    <i class="fa fa-plane text-muted" data-toggle="popover" title="Activer/Désactiver"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot class="tfoot">
        <mfBootstrapPaginator class="pagination"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

what is expected is :
 * when you click wherever you want on the row you go to the details
 * when you click on the delete you get the pop up of delete confirmation

Comment: You should use `stopPropagation` on the click event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation.

Comment: i don't know how to use it. i want to block editObjectEmmitter(obj) when i click deleteObjectEmmitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `stopPropagation` on event triggered by the click ([stopPropagation's doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation))

A thing like this:

```html
<a *ngIf="isDeleted" (click)='deleteObjectEmmitter(obj); $event.stopPropagation()'>
  <i class="icon-rubbish-bin text-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Supprimer"></i>
</a>
```

You can move the logic of propagation in you component, but this implies that your `deleteObjectEmitter` should accept another parameter

Comment: how? i want to block editObjectEmmitter(obj) when i click deleteObjectEmmitter